# Json.NET Schema can I emit non-standard properties in my schema?

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I automatically generate schema for my classes using Json.NET Schema and it works great for validation.  I wanted to add the ability for my classes to provide snippets directly and emit them into a (presumably separate) schema file, for use in Visual Studio Code.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_define-snippets-in-json-schemas

This is a non-standard schema extension of course.  From the source code of Json.NET Schema, it looks like I cannot override the class that is used to serialize the schema to JSON, so I can't figure out how to make this work.

The only approach I have considered is to emit the schema, read it back as dumb JSON and then edit in the snippets.  The resulting file could be a .vsschema or something like that and presumably no longer valid in the schema validator, so I would store it next to the "clean" one.   Is there any nice way to do this that doesn't require me to path through the resulting JSON and make edits that way?

Comment: It's probably bets to open a support ticket for the library in question. The JSON Schema team want to work with Microsoft to make such things part of standardised extensions to JSON Schema. We're working on it =]

Comment: @Relequestual haven't used JSON Schema since the very early days (draft 3, about 8 years ago.)  At that draft stage, it was definitely required to inherit the basic schema to make hyper-schema and other schema extensions.  Is that still how it is intended to work?

If so, it can reasonably be required that a schema library allow this.  Maybe there is a way to do it and I didn't spot it.   I am using Newtonsoft.   So presumably you meant create a ticket with them?  I do have paid support.

Comment: There's been a huge restructure in how JSON Schema works and can be extended for the latest draft. Tooling is yet to catch up. Yeah I would file support issue with Newtonsoft.